# ReactJS Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

```
 ...  
    renderSuggestion = suggestion => {
        return (
          <div className="result">
            <div>{suggestion.fullName}</div>
            <div className="shortCode">{suggestion.shortCode}</div>
          </div>
        );
      };
    ...
```

Its a tsx file

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Autosuggest from 'react-autosuggest';
import axios from 'axios';
import { debounce } from 'throttle-debounce';
import { root } from 'postcss';

class AutoComplete extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: '',
    suggestions: []
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested = debounce(500, this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested);
  }

  renderSuggestion = suggestion => return (
    <div className="result">
      <div>{suggestion.fullName}</div>
      <div className="shortCode">{suggestion.shortCode}</div>
    </div>
  );
  };

  onChange = (event, { newValue }) => {
    this.setState({ value: newValue });
  };

  onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value }) => {
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:9200/crm_app/customers/_search', {
        query: {
          multi_match: {
            query: value,
            fields: ['fullName', 'shortCode']
          }
        },
        sort: ['_score', { createdDate: 'desc' }]
      })
      .then(res => {
        const results = res.data.hits.hits.map(h => h._source);
        this.setState({ suggestions: results });
      });
  };

  onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
    this.setState({ suggestions: [] });
  };

  render() {
    const { value, suggestions } = this.state;

    const inputProps = {
      placeholder: 'customer name or short code',
      value,
      onChange: this.onChange
    };

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>AutoComplete Demo</h1>
        <Autosuggest
          suggestions={suggestions}
          onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
          onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
          getSuggestionValue={suggestion => suggestion.fullName}
          renderSuggestion={this.renderSuggestion}
          inputProps={inputProps}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<AutoComplete />, rootElement);
export default AutoComplete;
```

Comment: The question lacks the context that would allow to answer it. It's `...` that matters.

Comment: "Lambdas are forbidden in JSX attributes due to their rendering performance impact". I can only assume that the said lambda is what is affected to renderSuggestion, but we don't see how you are using it here. We would need the whole component to properly answer your question

Comment: @estus  updated question

Comment: What is the question? The title is just a linter warning as the code has unnecessary curly brackets

Comment: @dashton i'm learning react. trying to implement autocomplete in my spring app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your codes:

```
renderSuggestion = suggestion => return (
    <div className="result">
      <div>{suggestion.fullName}</div>
      <div className="shortCode">{suggestion.shortCode}</div>
    </div>
  );
  };
```

with this:

```
renderSuggestion = suggestion => (
    <div className="result">
      <div>{suggestion.fullName}</div>
      <div className="shortCode">{suggestion.shortCode}</div>
    </div>
  );
```

What I did is fixing some syntax errors. Hopefully, that helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is syntax error:

```
  renderSuggestion = suggestion => return (
    <div className="result">
      <div>{suggestion.fullName}</div>
      <div className="shortCode">{suggestion.shortCode}</div>
    </div>
  );
  };
```

It's either:

```
  renderSuggestion = suggestion => (
    <div className="result">
      <div>{suggestion.fullName}</div>
      <div className="shortCode">{suggestion.shortCode}</div>
    </div>
  );
```

Or:

```
  renderSuggestion = suggestion => {
  return (
    <div className="result">
      <div>{suggestion.fullName}</div>
      <div className="shortCode">{suggestion.shortCode}</div>
    </div>
  );
  };
```

Linter error refers to this prop:

```
getSuggestionValue={suggestion => suggestion.fullName}
```

It results in creating new function on every `render` call. This isn't a big overhead. It can be either defined as `this.getSuggestionValue` callback, or linter rule could be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error here:

```
renderSuggestion = suggestion => return (
    <div className="result">
      <div>{suggestion.fullName}</div>
      <div className="shortCode">{suggestion.shortCode}</div>
    </div>
);
```

To use "return" statement in "arrow-function" you need to open a block for function it-self.

Either do it like this:

```
renderSuggestion = () => {
    return (
        <div className="result">
          <div>{suggestion.fullName}</div>
          <div className="shortCode">{suggestion.shortCode}</div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Or you can immediately return value without opening function block like this :

```
renderSuggestion = suggestion => (
    <div className="result">
      <div>{suggestion.fullName}</div>
      <div className="shortCode">{suggestion.shortCode}</div>
    </div>
);
```